# SoftLayer: VM stuck at Reclaim Prep

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

SoftLayer VMs have the following pending transactions, VM can't be cancelled.

> 46649559
>   Started2017-01-25 03:48 PM (UTC-05:00)
>   GroupCloud Instance Reclaim
>   StatusReclaim network resources (RECLAIM_NETWORK)
>   Elapsed Time8 Minutes 17 Seconds

That looks like it hit the provisioning system but because it could not complete so the provisioning system is reclaiming the VSI instance. But why is it stuck at this state?

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue reported about this, it will be fixed very soon.

My apologies for the inconveniences, as soon as the fixed will be released, these transactions will run normally. If you prefer you can submit a ticket for tracking on this